# dx-scheduler ANGULAR - how to implement pagination in the scheduler with angular

Tags: angular, devexpress, scheduler

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKTBn.png)enter image description hereI want to implement a pagination for the scheduler dev extrem because I have a lot of grouped recording, the problem is that I tried with this code but it doesn't work  :

```
        this.chedulerDataSource = new DataSource({
        store: new CustomStore({
            loadMode: 'raw',
            load: () => {
                return this.intervenantData;
            },
        }),
        paginate: true,
        pageSize : 5,
     });
```

do you have any idea to implement paging for a devExpress scheduler ??

Answer (score 0):

In the Devextreme Docs for the scheduler, all of their examples have `paginate: false`.  They even specifically say this:

> NOTE
> Please review the following notes about data binding:
>
> If you wrap the store into the DataSource object explicitly, set the paginate option to false to prevent data from partitioning.

https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxScheduler/Configuration/#dataSource

I don't think it's possible.  You may have better luck [filing a ticket](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/list) on Devextreme. Sometimes there is some weird, undocumented way of doing things that one of their support staff respond with, or they look into adding it as a feature.

One thing to note is the `CustomStore.load()` method gets a parameter, you may be able to get something useful out of it to pass along to an API call

```js
store: new CustomStore({
        loadMode: 'raw',
        load: (options) => {
            return this.someMethod(options);
        },
    }),
```

Comment: thank you for your return, i will try to ask the question on devExpress support.

for the CustomStore I tried a lot of variant but it does not show me the buttons of the pages to navigate to: page 1 page 2 etc ...